# Creating a new virtual machine is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

My goal is to work with Twitter API and do a sentiment analysize on tweets.

I am Working on a MAC, with VS Code on Anaconda.
I followed the tutorial and installed: `python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv` in my Terminal:

```
(base) Ludwigs-MBP:~ ludwigmehmke$ python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv

Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.23)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from zipp>=0.5->importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (7.2.0)
(base) Ludwigs-MBP:~ ludwigmehmke$ 
(base) Ludwigs-MBP:~ ludwigmehmke$
```

This is what I get. Next step was to create a Virtual Machine in VS Code. I entered the terminal there and created following code:

```
Ludwigs-MBP:Python ludwigmehmke$ python3 -m venv venv
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: A Python virtualenv or a virtual machine? These could not be more different.

Comment: Btw you installed `virtualenv` and are trying to create it with `venv`. Those are somewhat similar but different packages.